# Как SQL запросом получить данные из текста?

Tags: mysql

У меня в SQL таблице лежит значение в текстовом формате:

```
<Feedback Id="1234">
    <PhoneChange ChangeId=1234>
        <Value>
            <Phone Contact="+7 999 999-99-99"></Phone>
        </Value>
    </PhoneChange>
</Feedback>
```

Как я могу запросом SQL получить только значение `+7 999 999-99-99`?

PS БД владею только на чтение.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Обычным select пробовали?

Comment: [ExtractValue() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)

Comment: @Wolframm, привет. возможно непонятно написал.
У меня например есть таблица с колонками:
id, text
В колонке text значения лежат в формате, который я описал выше, и мне по сути надо получить такое значение:
id - 1,  text - +7 999 999-99-99

Comment: Select text from yourTable where id=1

Comment: Wolframm, в таком случае, мне выведет id - 1, а в поле текст все значение:
<Feedback Id="1234">
<PhoneChange ChangeId=1234>
                <Value>
                    <Phone Contact="+7 999 999-99-99"></Phone>
                </Value>
            </PhoneChange>
</Feedback>
И мне из этого значения нужно только +7 999 999-99-99

Comment: Никак. Вам надо получить эту строку, и обработать ее. А как - зависит от того, на каком языке вы пишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql умеет работать с xml [через xpath запросы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html)

```
select
  ExtractValue(xml_column,'string(//Feedback/PhoneChange/Value/Phone/@Contact)') as phone
from my_table
```

Тестировать xpath можно [тут](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)

Comment: Не за что :) Там галочка специальная под ответом есть для "спасибов" :))))

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте такой вариант для MySQL

```
SELECT 
ExtractValue(text,'//Phone/@Contact') as phone
FROM   Test;
```

И у вас ошибка в синтаксисе XML. Надо так

```
<PhoneChange ChangeId="1234">
```

Comment: becouse, при выполнении возникает ошибка:
"Не удалось найти столбец "text", определяемую пользователем функцию или агрегатную функцию "text.value". Также возможно, имя является неоднозначным"

Comment: Я же не знаю структуру вашей БД. text это поле где xml. В зависимости от типа сервера может меняться синтаксис. Добавил еще вариант

Comment: becouse, если взять просто select text from [myTable], запрос проходит. Если задаю так text.value('(/Feedback/PhoneChang/Value/Phone@Contact', 'nvarchar(max)') или [text], то возникает подобная ошибка. Никакой @declare тут не должен фигурировать?

Comment: Без структуры БД и примера дампа сложно дать верный пример. Попробуйте вот так

Comment: Сервер БД явно указан тегом темы. Давать ответ для совершенно другого диалекта, неприменимый на требуемом диалекте, не очень правильно.